# BASH: $(date) in OSX results in "Illegal variable name"

Tags: bash, macos, variables

Within one of my bash script's I am using the `$(date)` variable, which seems to work fine in a LINUX environment. However, whe I try to use the script on OSX I get errors:

```
echo $(date)
--> Illegal variable name.
```

Ultimately, I would like to call the date function in both enviroments by the same way:

```
testvar=$(date +%s.%N)
```

Do you have an idea for a workaround on OSX? Maybe a custom function that will work in both environments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your shell do this: `type date` and show the output here

Comment: @fuz What's that supposed to do? There's no word-splitting performed for variable assignment, so the double quotes are not needed (but don't hurt either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're using [csh](/questions/tagged/csh) (The C Shell) or [tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh):

```
# ps
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
 37950 pts/51   00:00:00 csh
 37951 pts/51   00:00:00 ps
# echo $(date)
Illegal variable name.
# echo `date`
Thu Mar 23 17:30:02 CST 2017
# set date=`date`
# echo $date
Thu Mar 23 17:31:43 CST 2017
#
```

To use `bash`:

```
# bash
bash-4.4# echo $(date)
Thu Mar 23 17:28:19 CST 2017
bash-4.4#
```